# Scraping information from multiple collapsible tables

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I'd like to scrape information from the collapsible tables within the "nutrient nitrogen" tab of this web page http://www.apis.ac.uk/select-feature?site=1001814&SiteType=SSSI&submit=Next

I have been trying to use:

```
url <- "http://www.apis.ac.uk/select-feature?site=1001814&SiteType=SSSI&submit=Next.html"  
html<-read_html(url)  
html %>%
  html_node("table.tab-tables") %>%
  html_text()
```

I can seem to see what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated as I'm quite new to R

Comment: If you prefer to pandas and requests then I can help you this way

Answer (score 0):

The website loads additional contents when the site is opened in the browser. In order to get these content chunks you'd have to either simulate regular browser behavior ([RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/index.html) can help with that) or you can dig into the network requests your browser makes when surfing the site. You can do that in Firefox by right clicking anywhere on the page and click on "Inspect". The Inspect interface opens and you'll see several tabs one says "Network". Click that and reload the page. You will see the requests being listed. It should work similar in Chrome. By doing that I found that there are requests that correspond with each of the tabs shown on the website (Nutrient Nitrogen etc.). You can copy the request URL of the tab you are interested in and visit that in your browser and you'll see that it displays the pages content without any decoration and navigation elements.

This you can now scrape easily, like this:

```
library(rvest)
nnut_url <- "http://www.apis.ac.uk/sites/default/files/AJAX/srcl_2019/apis_tab_nnut.php?ajax=true&site=1001814&BH=&populateBH=true"

nnut_dom <- read_html(nnut_url)  

nnut_dom %>% 
  html_table()
```

It might be worth your time to get in contact with the organization behind the site and suggest to them to include a raw data download. That would make it easier in general for other people to use their data.